# Change logo based on country - website blogger

Tags: html, css, web, blogger

Hello stack overflow i like to ask a question I am looking everywhere but I didn't found anything can someone tell me how can I change my blogger.com website logo according to country 
eg: if user is from USA then logo will change to website name (USA) if you are from canada then logo will say website name (CANADA)

plz help

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a geolocation API to detect their origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Or perhaps looking up the IP.

https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/

Comment: ty for info micheal

Answer (score -1):

not sure how to do this exactly, but you might want to look into reading out IP addresses, because they will reveal where people most likely come from

Comment: ty josen I will look into it but I want something like a code example